# PCB Pad sizes: Is it worth going over Level A of IPC-2221?

Tags: pcb, pad

All is in the title. I've been using [this "guide"](http://www.pcb-3d.com/tutorials/how-to-calculate-pth-hole-and-pad-diameter-sizes-according-to-ipc-7251-ipc-2222-and-ipc-2221-standards/) to calculate PTH pad diameters. 
I'd like to comply at least with Level A of IPC-2221. Apparently it just means that the pad has to be 0.7 mm (275 mils) larger than the hole size.

However, some of the built-in Kicad footprints (in my case Connectors_Molex:Molex_MiniFit-JR-5556-24A_2x12x4.20mm_Straight, aka 24 pin ATX motherboard header), have a pad size about 1.5mm (600 mils) larger than the hole size.

So again, my question is: Is it worth going over the 0.7mm spec? (does it really make it easier to solder the pins?) In my opinion, it's more negative than positive. What do you think?

Comment: Increased pad area can increase heat conduction to the PCB, and increase the strength of mechanical support. Whether these matter depends on the component and the design.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In my specific case, I don't think I'll have to worry about heat dissipation too much. But the amount of stress introduced by weight of the 24 16AWG cables might be an issue. So I think I'll leave 0.7mm for most pads except for those headers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Small surface mount pads peel off really easily. It is not really an issue with through hole though due to the adhesion of the plated through hole, the solder in the hole taking all the shear, and a pad/solder on one side of the PCB takes all the thrust force through compression reducing tension and peel of the pad on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that chip components 0805 and smaller can be rather difficult to hand solder when the pads are sized exactly to the chip for the purposes of reflow.

The reason is that when the pads are sized exactly to the component terminals, it can be tricky to have the iron make contact with both the terminal and the pad. You might inadvertently push the component a bit to reveal more of the pad but in doing so you shove the other terminal far enough that you can't make contact its pad anymore.

It really helps if you have hot tweezers where you can fine position the component to make sure both terminals are making contact or a hoof tip that is only tinned on the face and not the edges so it can hold a huge solder bead that can actually flow around and get under the terminal when it is a bit over the edge of the pad (but it still isn't always perfect).

And it can be extremely tedious with a chisel tip.

This is not an issue with other components though where terminals are exposed and low to the pad

---

Pad size matters even less for through hole since you don't need the molten solder to center the component on the pad during reflow or prevent tombstoning.

Small surface mount pads peel off really easily so larger pads help there but it is not really an issue with through hole though due to the adhesion of the plated through hole, the solder in the hole taking all the shear, and a pad/solder on one side of the PCB takes all the thrust force through compression reducing tension and peel of the pad on the other side.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I forgot to mention that I'm only working with through hole components... The smallest one I'm working with is a 1/2W resistor.

Comment: See the last line I edited in.

Answer (score 1):

The PTH dimensions classes in IPC-2221 mostly concerns manufacturing, what tolerances and dimension that is needed for a manufacturer to be able to produce the PCB according to it's own abilities of precision.

Mostly you like bigger pads to have better solderability of components or for even stronger mounting of the components